# Conjugacy Classes in $\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, free-product

May I know what are the conjugacy classes of the group $\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}$ (the free product of infinite cyclic groups by itself)?

Answer (score 2):

This group is more commonly known as the free group of rank $2$.

Every element of a free group is conjugate to a cyclically reduced word, and two cyclically reduced words are conjugate if and only if one is a cyclic permutation of the other. So it is easy to decide when two elements are conjugate.

For example, in the free group with generators $a$ and $b$, the element $aba^2b^{-1}ab^{-1}a^{-1}$ is conjugate to the cyclically reduced word $a^2b^{-1}a$, which is conjugate to $ab^{-1}a^2$, $b^{-1}a^3$ and $a^3b^{-1}$.

Comment: And if OP wants *really* rigorous treatment of this question, it can be found in Magnus&Carrass&Solitar, Combinatorial Group Theory, 1.4.

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer! Also thank you @xsnl for the reference!